# Arabic is converted to ???? after committing in oracle

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, arabic

I am new in oracle, and I have an issue concerning Arabic characters. Actually I have a stored procedure that is working fine except with Arabic parameters, It converts them to ??? after I commit. Here is an example [before commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsFoT.png)  and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQrj2.png).

I am using oracle 10g client and query "select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET'; " is returning AR8MSWIN1256.

Any idea how to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which tool do you use to insert and select the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

Go to control Panel -> System and security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment variables -> in System variables section check if NLS_LANG exists, if yes set value ARABIC_AMERICA.AL32UTF8, if no add a new one.

And regedit -> HLM -> Software -> Oracle -> Key_name_home1 set NLS_LANG value as ARABIC_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

Restart your pc
NB: this solution is for windows 2007, 64 bit